# What is the difference between place-items and align-items?

Tags: html, css

Would like to know what's the difference between using

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

or

```
display: flex;
place-items: center;
```

Visually it looks the same, place-items has 90% browser support, align-items has 92%.

Case (should have fixed width container, and align icon in the middle)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="icon> <svg ... /> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `place-items` is a shorthand for `align-items` and `justify-items`, mainly used by `grid` layout. For `flex` layout, `justify-items` does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

> The CSS `place-items` shorthand property sets the `align-items` **and** `justify-items` properties, respectively. If the second value is not set, the first value is also used for it.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items)</sup>

So no, they are not the same.

---

And from [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#place-items-property):

> This shorthand property sets both the align-items and justify-items properties in a single declaration. The first value is assigned to align-items. The second value is assigned to justify-items; if omitted, it is copied from the first value.

Even if in the actual Flexbox iteration `justify-items` is not defined and will have no effect, you should not consider them the same because things may change in the future.

> justify-items
>
> This property specifies the default justify-self for all of the child boxes (including anonymous boxes) participating in this box’s formatting context. Values have the following meanings

And

> justify-self
>
> Justifies the box (as the alignment subject) within its containing block (as the alignment container) along the inline/row/main axis of the alignment container

and

> 6.1.4. Flex Items
>
> This property does not apply to flex items, because there is more than one item in the main axis. See flex for stretching and justify-content for main-axis alignment. [CSS-FLEXBOX-1]